# log4j - Log statements in code not redirected to console

Tags: java, log4j

I am learning Hibernate with Spring and am creating an application using the same with JSF 2.0. I am trying to configure the logging in my application but the log statements in my code do not seem to get sent to the output (console in my case).

I can see the Hibernate logging statements though :|

Following is my project structure :

[image: structure snapshot]

And my **log4j.properties** :

```
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info
log4j.logger.org.springframework=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql.ast.AST=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.type=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl=warn
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.hql=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.cache=info
log4j.logger.org.hibernate.jdbc=info
```

And here's the code for the context listener class:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
...
...
...

public class HibernateListener implements ServletContextListener 
{
   private static final String CFG_PATH = "/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml";

   private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(HibernateListener.class);

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
      HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().close();
   }

   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
      URL configFile = null;
      try {
         configFile = event.getServletContext().getResource(CFG_PATH);
         HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(configFile);
         LOGGER.info("Context initialization successful");
         System.out.println("Context initialization successful");
      }
      catch (MalformedURLException e) {
         System.err.println("Could not load hibernate configuration file - " + configFile);
      }
   }
}
```

I can't see the INFO statement nor the sysout...

Comment: It seems like everything is fine with your log4j.properties file. Where do you run your application? Where do you look for the log messages?

Comment: I run my app in Eclipse using Tomcat 7 as app server. All the visible logs are currently printed in the console...

Comment: Do you have the same log4j.properties inside your project in the Tomcat application directories? You should look in ${YOUR_WORKSPACE}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0 directory, in both "wtpwebapps" and "work" directories.

Comment: @ArtemShafranov : I checked the directories you mentioned but I don't see another log4j.properties file. However, there does exist a copy in the `wtpwebapps\${PROJECT_NAME}\WEB-INF\classes` in the TOMCAT program directory...

Comment: Tomcat folder also has its own copy of log4j.properties in the `lib` folder...

Comment: Is there the same configuration in the log4j.properties file that you found as the configuration that you've posted?

Comment: I just checked and it seems something is wrong with the app server... it is not showing the "Server startup in n secs" message anymore. I'll create a fresh new server configuration and update about the same...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there WAS an issue with app server starting due to which the code never reached the LOG statement. Problem resolved after creating fresh instance of the application server...

Comment: I think it was the problem with deployment on previous server actually. But I'm glad that you was able to solve the problem.